# 2D matrix of QStrings

Tags: qt, list, qt4

I want to make an application with which you can reserve ticket for your travel. In fact, I'm designing the system for an airline. When I want to create a database (a 2D matrix that saves the number of seats in flights), it gives me errors.

The number of flights set in different place and the number is changing this is my code:

```
QString** matrix = new QString*[numberofFlights];
for (int i = 0; i < numberofFlight; i++)
{
  matrix[i] = new QString[numberofSeats];
}
```

What class in Qt should i use?

Comment: I'm uncertain as to what you are actually asking. You mention an error without saying what the error is. Since this is not your first question, the expectations of question quality will be higher. There are formatting tools available in the question editor. When you look at your own question, are you pleased with how it looks?

Answer (score 2):

A must-read: [Qt container classes](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/containers.html).

You could use `QVector`s or `QList`s or another container class. For example, to build a vector of vectors:

```
QVector< QVector<QString> > matrix(numberOfFlights);
for (int i=0; i<numberOfFlights; i++)
   matrix[i].fill("", numberOfSeats);
```

This will create `numberOfFlights` vectors, that each contain `numberOfSeats` empty strings.

To set a specific seat:

```
matrix[flight][seat] = "whatever";
```

You can iterate over the vectors with the usual Qt `foreach`, or iterators, or plain `for`.