# 2-dimensional vector in class scope

Tags: c++, qt, qvector

I want to have an 2 dimensional vector containing strings so i tried something like that:

```
QVector<QVector<QString*> > register_options(8, QVector<QString*>(8)); //getting 'expected identifier before numeric constant'
QVector<QVector<QString> > register_options; // getting 'field has incomplete type'
```

this is the initialisation I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333783/2d-matrix-of-qstrings)

I also read that its not possible no initialize vectors in class scope and should be done in the constructor, which I understand however I can't define the prototype of the var in class scope.

I also tried

```
//header
QVector<QString> register_bits; // field has incomplete type
QVector<QVector<QString> > register_options; // field has incomplete type
//source
registers::registers() : register_bits(8, 0), register_options(8, register_bits)
{ //...
```

So my question is: how to define the vector in the class scope and then initialize it in the constructor?

Comment: Are you familiar with C++ initializer lists? Maybe that's what you need here. However, I have no idea how Qt works, just concluded this from the last sentence.

Comment: After edit: header means in class, or global scope?

Comment: "has incompelte type" suggests you forgot to include required header

Comment: @errikos fixed title, i mean class scope

Comment: @M.M thx this also brought me to the solution, i forgot the header files to include for QString an QVector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So my question is: how to define the vector in the class scope and
>   then initialize it in the constructor?

One of possible ways to initialize such structure in memory with C++ 11 initializer list:

```
class MyClass
{
private:
    QVector<QVector<QString> > vct {{"", ""}, {""}, {"", "", ""}};
};
```

Or in line:

```
QVector<QVector<QString> > vct = {{"", ""}, {""}, {"", "", ""}};
```

Or in constructor or any class' method:

```
vct = {{"", ""}, {""}, {"", "", ""}};
```

I tried and that compiles and should work. The above pattern is actually an [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) as original poster asked in comments.

Comment: after haveing this [problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28075328/could-not-convert-from-brace-enclosed-initializer-list-to-stdvector) it was working but I have one question left. For what are the braces? it is some kind of random initialisation right?

Comment: There is new initializer list in C++ 11 and aggregate initializer list too: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization